# ¿Qué significan 'mazado', 'marcado', y 'marcar' en este contexto?

Tags: significado, adjetivos, verbo-pronominal, significado-en-contexto

> Molan las fotos, se te ve delgadete pero duro y ***marcado***......y mola tu nabo  así que aunque buscaba ***mazado***, contigo vale igual ...

> Si tienes bus o algo para venir, [...]
> Dicho esto, que te molaria hacer: que rollo que t mola en sexo ...aparte de que me molara verte cuerpo como te ***marcas*** ver tu fuerza tocarte músculos y eso....

La persona a la que se refiere el escritor es atlética y fuerte pero sin hipertrofia muscular excesiva.
Mis preguntas:

1. ¿Significa *[mazado](https://dle.rae.es/mazar?m=form)* muy musculoso en este contexto?
2. ¿Qué significa *[marcado](https://dle.rae.es/marcado?m=form)* y *[marcar](https://dle.rae.es/marcar?m=form)* en este contexto?

Comment: mazazo, built, marcado, ripped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.- ¿Significa "**mazado**" muy musculoso en este contexto?.

2.- ¿Qué significa **marcado y marcar** en este contexto?.

En general los tres términos se refieren a lo mismo y obviamente están relacionados con los músculos.

- **Mazazo**, se refiere a una persona que esta "**maciza**", musculada, firme y consistente.
  Cuando alguien es atractivo o está muy bien, también se dice que esta "macizo".

**Mazado / Mazada**

*adj. y n. masc. o fem. Con músculos notablemente marcados, fuerte, musculoso, fornido.
Mi amigo Carlos ha estado todo el invierno haciendo pesas y ahora está mazado. Es coloquial.*

*Etimología*

*De mazarse, posiblemente relacionado con maza o mazo, o quizá con mazar ‘golpear’, porque quien está mazado aguanta bien los golpes. También podría estar relacionado con masa, como macizo.*

https://diccet.com/2020/10/09/mazado-mazada/

---

- **Marcado y marcar**

Ambos se refieren a lo mismo, a los músculos firmes, tersos y suficientemente tonificados y definidos, al punto que resultan llamativos y "**marcan**" un cuerpo atractivo para muchas personas. Normalmente se dice "marcar músculo/s".

> *Para **marcar músculos** de forma rápida, hay que ir aumentando la cantidad de peso que se levanta. Si son demasiado pesadas, sólo vas a
> estar trabajando el peso en vez de tus músculos, pero si usas pesas
> que sean demasiada livianas, entonces no añades la intensidad
> necesaria para definir la musculatura*

*Tips para marcar músculos rápidamente*

https://okdiario.com/salud/tips-marcar-musculos-rapidamente-75994

Answer (score 0):

Marcado se refiere a que tiene marcados los músculos, a que tiene bien definidos sus bordes.

Comment: Hay buenas y malas maneras (jaja) para hablar de lo que dice los otros.

Comment: Pues con buenas maneras lo que se hace es dar cuerda a gente que claramente no sabe lo que está poniendo. Encima poniendo párrafos y párrafos como si eso lo hiciese más creíble. Con un poco de malhumor esta gente se llevaría la desinformación a otro sitio.